# simple subquery not working DB2

Tags: sql, db2, relational-database

hey guys this is a very simple sql query that is not giving me the correct result.

subquery:

```
SELECT NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS.MEMBER_ID
FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS
WHERE NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS.ORDERS_ID = 6371043
```

this subquery successfully returns a correct value 627809

simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ADDRESS
WHERE MEMBER_ID IN (627809)
```

this query executes properly and returns 4 rows.(4 addresses for a member)
but if I try to combine these queries in 1 query as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ADDRESS
WHERE MEMBER_ID IN (
        SELECT NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS.MEMBER_ID
        FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS
        WHERE NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS.ORDERS_ID = 6371043
        )
```

then the query returns 0 rows. why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: can you not use a `join`?

Comment: i could use a join, but I'd like to know why my subquery is not working

Comment: ...okay, do joins work anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks OK, the only I can think is maybe you mistake the value on the result.

can you try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ADDRESS
WHERE MEMBER_ID IN (
        SELECT 627809
        FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS
        WHERE NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS.ORDERS_ID = 6371043
        )
```

and this

```
SELECT *
FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ADDRESS
WHERE MEMBER_ID IN (
        SELECT 627809
        FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS            
        )
```

Comment: What datatype is `MEMBER_ID` in `ORDERS` and what type is in `ADDRESS`

Comment: BIGINT in both tables

Comment: Then your first query doesnt return a value.  `WHERE NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS.ORDERS_ID = 6371043` doesnt have any row. the problem is the `ID = 6371043` isnt on `ORDERS`

Comment: trust me, it is. the very first query in my question returns a single row because ORDERS_ID is a primary key for that table

Comment: I want trust you but doesnt make sense. Unless you broke db2 :P.  if you try only `SELECT 627809
        FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS
        WHERE NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS.ORDERS_ID = 6371043` that return something?

Comment: i know it doesn't make sense that's why I'm on SO. your EXACT query gives this: 
 1      
 ------ 
 627809 

 1 record(s) selected [Fetch MetaData: 1ms] [Fetch Data: 11ms] 

 [Executed: 20/11/2015 11:15:07 AM] [Execution: 55ms]

Comment: In theory such things might happen if there is a corrupted index on one of the tables. However, human error is more probable.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Order (presumably) can only carry a single Member_ID -- can you please try your full query without the "IN", rather try an equal join as follows:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ADDRESS
    WHERE MEMBER_ID = (
    SELECT NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS.MEMBER_ID
    FROM NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS
    WHERE NEODB2ADMIN.ORDERS.ORDERS_ID = 6371043
    )
```

Comment: well this is not a join, it is also a subquery, but I already tried it and it does not work either :(

Comment: Try recasting each side as text and see if it runs.  Is it possible that environmental factors (schemas, synonyms, grants) have you querying a different table than you think?